# С++ | Отредактировать предложение, удаляя из него слова, которые уже встречались

Tags: c++

***Добрый вечер, форум.*** Есть задача в практике, к сожалению, который час сижу и не могу понять как её решать. Звучит она так:

> Отредактировать данное предложение, удаляя из него слова, которые уже
>   встречались в предложении раньше.

Предложение в задачи не дано, так что полагаю под данным предложением имеется ввиду предложение, веденное пользователем.

Разрешенные заголовочные файлы в использовании:
stdio.h
string.h
( ну и естественно еще iostream, просто решил опустит это, ибо это очевидно ).

Буду благодарен за помощь. P.S. 1 курс.

Comment: Что за дичь такая в С++: "разрешённые библиотеки stdio.h string.h". Чем тогда это отличается от C?

Comment: Я бы хотел расширить список,но в вузе иного мы не проходили пока что, а если используем сторонние заголовочные файлы ( даже если самостоятельно изучили их и на зубок докажем это ), то нам не зачтут задание.

Comment: В Си/С++ Не Библиотеки, А Заголовочные Файлы!!!

Comment: Извиняюсь, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Ну тут можно запоминать введенные пользователем слова - класть их в ассоциативный контейнер (например std::unordered_set). Затем при вводе нового слова - проверять встречалось ли оно раньше. Если встречалось - не выводим, если не встречалось - выводим, а это слово добавляем в контейнер. Больше всего головной боли принесет парсинг входной строки - ну тут можно по тупому (по пробелам))

Comment: Очень сложно для первого курса. Но ход мысли я уловил. Попробую реализовать подобное через массив. В который будут попадать слова а потом каждое новое проверяться на то встречалось ли оно или нет прогоняясь через этот массив. Спасибо:)

Comment: @Lofectr. не заголовочные файлы а компоненты libstdc++ уж....

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

char* del(char* inStr)
{
    char* newStr = new char[strlen(inStr) + 1]; // Итоговая (результирующая) строка
    char* bufStr = new char[strlen(inStr) + 1]; // Буфер обмена (хранение текущего слова)
    *newStr = '\0'; // "Обнуляем" результирующую строку newStr
    int i = 0;      // Индекс текщей позиции в буфере
    while (true)
    {
        if (*inStr == ' ' || *inStr == '\0')
        {
            bufStr[i] = '\0'; // "Замыкаем" буфер обмена
            if (strstr(newStr, bufStr) == NULL) // Ищем в результирующей строке слово расположенное в буфере
            {
                strcat(newStr, bufStr); // Добовляем в конец результирующей строки слово из буфера
            }
            while (*inStr == ' ') // Пропускаем все пробелы и запятые
            {
                int len = strlen(newStr);
                newStr[len] = *inStr++; // Тупо добавляем эти символы в результирующую строку
                newStr[len + 1] = '\0'; // "Замыкаем"
            }
            i = 0; // Заново забиваем буфер
        }
        if (*inStr == '\0') // Ну, это для выхода
        {
            break;
        }
        bufStr[i++] = *inStr++; // Копируем текущей символ с входной строки в буфер
    }
    delete bufStr;
    return newStr;
}

int main()
{
    char* t = new char[255]; // на время выделяется память (с запасом) под строку 
    cin.getline(t, 255); // чтение строки

    char* s = new char[strlen(t) + 1]; // выделяется новая память под размер введённой строки
    strcpy(s, t); // копируется строка в новую память

    delete[] t; // ненужная память освобождается

    s = del(s);
    cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```